# http.get randomly says "getaddrinfo: Name or service not known"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, net-http

To generate offline reports, my Rails app needs to download charts from the Google Charts API.

**PROBLEM:** It works fine most of the time, but sometimes (randomly) it fails and says `getaddrinfo: Name or service not known`

When I get the error, I just relaunch the generation and usually it is successful.
Is it usual? Is there a best practice to protect against this?
Maybe a re-entrant algorithm, or a more high-level method?

Current code:

```
require 'net/http'
  charts.each_with_index do |path, index|
    Net::HTTP.start("chart.googleapis.com") do |http|
    resp = http.get(path)
    open("tmp/charts/chart" + index.to_s + ".png" ,"wb") do |file|
        file.write(resp.body)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

... it seems, you are overloading your DNS mechanism. Try this:

```
require 'net/http'
  Net::HTTP.start("chart.googleapis.com") do |http|
    charts.each_with_index do |path, index|
      resp = http.get(path)
      open("tmp/charts/chart" + index.to_s + ".png" ,"wb") do |file|
        file.write(resp.body)
      end
    end
  end
end
```